# Scan barcode from an image in gallery android

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, image-gallery

I'm creating a android project, main feature is scan barcode.

I'm tried integrate with [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/) library into my project, and it's work fine.

However, it's seems not support scan barcode from an available image in gallery of android devices.

How i can do it? or with other barcode library?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use this class [MultiFormatReader](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/MultiFormatReader.java) from ZXing library.

You have to get Gallery image in BitMap and convert it as this:

```
Bitmap bMap = [...];
String contents = null;

int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];  
//copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array  
bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());  

LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
contents = result.getText();
```

**UPDATE1**

To manipulate big image, please have a look at :

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

You could use this property [android:largeHeap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) to increase heap size.

Comment: @MítTơLớp, Is it useful ?

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply.

I tried your code and for some pictures, it's work greate.

But some other picture, it's crashes at:

int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

with Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: How do i can fix that bugs ? Please.

Comment: @MítTơLớp, I think some pictures are too big. What's size of your picture when it crash ?

Comment: Yep. It's 3264 x 2448. I tested on galaxy s3.

Comment: I'm resize image bitmap after get image from gallery, and it worked. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi. I ticked your answer is useful one week ago :D

Comment: Hi @LaurentY 
I pull source code Zxing from github but it don't support on android 2.3 . 
I tried use a Zxing's custom at https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner and it worked on android 2.3 . 
How do i can get image bitmap to display and save it in sdcard same as:  
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java#L538-L544 
Do you known ?

Comment: I tried by that way. But on android 2.3, it display "Camera using...Please reboot." (sdk > 14 ok)
I reboot but don't change.
While i use above custom, it's worked.
Now, I just need get image bitmap to store in sdcard.

Comment: Hi. 
I'm done. 
It's here: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/issues/76#issuecomment-95319443

Answer (score 3):

I have a working sample on how to implement this, if you reading in 2016 here is how I did it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //initialize variables to make them global
    private ImageButton Scan;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
  //for easy manipulation of the result
     public String barcode;

//call oncreate method
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //cast neccesary variables to their views
        Scan = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ScanBut);

        //set a new custom listener
        Scan.setOnClickListener(this);
        //launch gallery via intent
        Intent photoPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPic.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPic, SELECT_PHOTO);
    }

    //do necessary coding for each ID
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()){
             case R.id.ScanBut:
                 //launch gallery via intent
                 Intent photoPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                 photoPic.setType("image/*");
                 startActivityForResult(photoPic, SELECT_PHOTO);
                       break;
         }
    }

//call the onactivity result method
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//doing some uri parsing
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        //getting the image
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //decoding bitmap
                    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    Scan.setImageURI(selectedImage);// To display selected image in image view
                    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth() * bMap.getHeight()];
                    // copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
                    bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),
                            bMap.getHeight());

                    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(),
                            bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
                    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();// use this otherwise
                    // ChecksumException
                    try {
                        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
                        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
                        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);

                        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
         //*I have created a global string variable by the name of barcode to easily manipulate data across the application*//
                        barcode =  result.getText().toString();

                           //do something with the results for demo i created a popup dialog
                        if(barcode!=null){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                            builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                            builder.setMessage("" + barcode);
                            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                            alert1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });

                            alert1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                            alert1.show();}
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                            builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                            builder.setMessage("Nothing found try a different image or try again");
                            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                            alert1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });

                            alert1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                            alert1.show();

                        }
                     //the end of do something with the button statement.

                    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something weird happen, i was probably tired to solve this issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FormatException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Barcode/QR format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something weird happen, i was probably tired to solve this issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding *how* this code answers the question will help future visitors.

Comment: @LucienMendela Thank you. it work....but it only scan black and white png..how to scan qr with different color?

Comment: And issue is same it worked for most of image but does not for same. To validate if generated QR image is right or not, I checked with **online tool** (http://qrlogo.kaarposoft.dk/qrdecode.html) and it is able to decode successfully. I have strong feeling that something missing at mobile SDK side from Zxing.

Answer (score 1):

First, of course, read the image from the gallery (this can be in your activity):
[Help by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427308/how-to-scan-qr-code-from-imagenot-form-camera)

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    pickIntent.setDataAndType( android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");

    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 111);
```

After that, just get the image uri on the activity result and then ZXing will do the magic:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            //the case is because you might be handling multiple request codes here
            case 111:
                if(data == null || data.getData()==null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "The uri is null, probably the user cancelled the image selection process using the back button.");
                    return;
                }
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try
                {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    if (bitmap == null)
                    {
                        Log.e("TAG", "uri is not a bitmap," + uri.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                    int width = bitmap.getWidth(), height = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
                    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    bitmap = null;
                    RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);
                    BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                    MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
                    try
                    {
                        Result result = reader.decode(bBitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "The content of the QR image is: " + result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (NotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("TAG", "decode exception", e);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.e("TAG", "can not open file" + uri.toString(), e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in between of same scenario, where it throw **NotFoundException**, [official doc](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/index.html?com/google/zxing/NotFoundException.html) says

> Thrown when a barcode was not found in the image. It might have been
>   partially detected but could not be confirmed.

**First level solution**
 at some extend *@Laurent* answer worked almost for every sample I have but failed for few.

**Next level solution** adding decodeHints before to reader.decode(..) suggested by @Lucien Mendela did the trick.

```
Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE); // Not required in my case
decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

**But final things that worked for me**

- If you have big image you may have to scale down.
- It also require a ~rectangle shape (421*402 in my case I did).

**Reference**
Adding couple of similar issue filed across:

- [Random com.google.zxing.NotFoundException during the reading valid QRCode](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/748)

Tools you can use to validate image you have:

- [qrdecode](http://qrlogo.kaarposoft.dk/qrdecode.html) (Don't forgot to select check "Produce debug output" for debug info)
- [Zxing Decoder online](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx)